# Circle turns into ellipse after converting it into raster in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, circle

I have a polygon layer that contains a circle and an irregular polygon and I want to convert it into a raster in ArcGIS Pro. When I do that, the result is a raster containing the irregular polygon and an ellipse shape, not circle! I checked the projection and it is the same and the irregular polygon raster looks fine with no distortion. I need the circle to maintain its shape with no distortion. I am not sure what the problem is.

[image: Polygon layer to be converted to raster]

[image: The resulting raster]
[image: Tool used]
[image: Projection and settings]

Comment: This seems to clearly be a case of working/displaying in different CRSs.

Comment: But the other polygon did not change. It is the circle only that changed. If it is CRS, then shouldn't both of them change? they are all in the same layer.

Comment: Not sure why it would matter, but what sort of layer are you working with? Is it one with a explicit circle type (unlike shapefiles which would approximate the circle by a polygon)? It's a bit surprising that the circle in the layer file displays as a circle in the projection (depending on scale and other factors). What happens when you try a different projection? The circle should no longer be a circle. Maybe if you give us a lat/lon, someone can suggest a projection that should really distort the shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the map CRS was different than my layers. I am not sure why it didn't take the CRS of the first added layer!